# bootstrapValidator Validator Not Working due to Javascript conflicts?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap Validator(bootstrapValidator.js) for form validations. With this I added jQuery UI Multiselect [component](http://www.quasipartikel.at/multiselect/) in to my bootstrap page. But this component requires 1.5.1/jquery.min.js and Bootstrap Validator requires jquery-1.10.2.min.js, Because of this two different version on the same page validator is not working. If I use only updated version of Js (jquery-1.10.2.min.js) then Multiselect component stops working. Please help....

Comment: did you try to leave just 1.10.2 version? usually there are not so many things that could really require older version of jquery

Answer (score 1):

try to add the files in the order:

1. js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js
2. js/jquery-ui.js (if file exists in the project :))
3. jquery.min.js (1.5.1)
4. js/bootstrap.min.js (if file exists in the project :))
5. js/bootstrapValidator.min.js (if file exists in the project :))
6. other js

if it does not work http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried inncluding all js and css files in the head tag, and include order is critical: first include jquery library, next bootstrap, next plugin for validator. Then check your html code for errors. I found this tutoral online [http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Powerful-Form-Validation-Plugin-For-jQuery-Bootstrap-3.html]

```
<head>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Style_sheet.css" type="text/css" /> -->
    <title>The Transformers</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="/title_icon2.jpg">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- // <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script> -->


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/docs.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.1/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.1/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>

</head>
```